# Using Regression to predict target variable of small range

Tags: regression, random-forest, descriptive-statistics, range

I am using Random Forest regression (of scikit-learn). In the train set, the target variables only range from 1-6 ( & they can meaningfully, only be integers, in my case). The target variables are not factor levels. After training, I am getting a very poor accuracy in prediction on test as the model easily gets it wrong. Since the target range is so small, even if it predicts a '3' for a '2', it becomes a poor result.

I have tried changing the RF model hyper-parameters but they all only result in better fit of the train set. The test-performance remains poor. Is there any statistical approach/model-building that can help me improve prediction for target variables with very small range?

Comment: Are you sure that your problem is regression and not classification?